# Javascript after window.print() sometimes executes before the print dialog, sometimes after

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a web page with a "Print" button.  The effect I want is that after the print dialog is completed through either a print or cancel, the page thanks the user for using our site.

The print function looks roughly like the following:

```
function printThenThank() {
  window.print();
  $('.thankYou').removeClass('hidden');
  // alert('debug message');
}
```

The trouble I'm finding is that sometime the "hidden" thank you message shows up in the printout, and sometimes it doesn't.  I've run it multiple times, sometimes with the debug message alert preceding the print modal, and sometimes alerting only after the print request is cancelled.

I originally believed `window.print()` to be a synchronous call, but it seems to behave more like an asynchronous trigger for a process with a modal dialog.

Is there any reliable cross-platform way of ensuring that the content rewrites I want to perform aren't initiated until after the user has chosen to print or cancel from the window.print() dialog?

Comment: why not use settimeout for this case?

Comment: I don't care for setTimeout for race conditions.  If I set it too short, it can still redraw page elements before rendered for print.  If too long, my page appears to hang for a quick user who cancelled right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combat race conditions, You could try triggering the thank you with a setTimeout, but that will indeed only work if the call is synchronous. I wouldn't rely on that for all browsers.

Instead what you want to do is hide the thank you from the print even if it's there:

HTML:

```
<div class="thankYou no-print">Thanks for printing</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media print {    
  .no-print, .no-print *
  {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.  While I didn't state it, there are additional page elements that I want hidden after print, so the "thank you" message replaces other content.  I can use the same technique you describe to hide those only for `@media screen` but keep them visible to `@media print`.